# Sorting a row by emptiness along another row with a specific date

Tags: google-sheets

I have made a goal organization spreadsheet so that I can be more organized and productive in reaching my goals.  So far I have my goals spread out on a sheet with a lot of white space in between making it useful but their is a need to do unnecessary scrolling.

For now I have two sheets.  One called Goals which will print the data that will be sorted.  The other sheet is Goals input.  I'd like to have the dates remain with the non empty cells in the same chronological order.  I'd also like to have this done with not just one row sorted with the dates, but multiple rows (goals) to be sorted against the date.

Here's a link to a sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rp3z84DLfJyNmurAzLem0dbYtBbZTCYQfLMCbmAjec0/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Here are some images of what I have so far.  The first is the default.  There is empty space on row 18 I'd like to remove and also the empty rows below it.

[image]

**Second image with row 18 missing, empty rows below cleared, while keeping chronological order.  I manually removed the rows etc. to show what I wanted it to look like.**